# For the state of "legend" can increase filtering function?

Tags: website-design, user-expectation, design

As shown in figure, can click "Completed", the list will filter out green "Completed"? Similar to a dropdown.

After clicking,"legend" should have what kind of visual feedback? Or add a chekbox in front of the "legend" ?

Who's seen a similar example ？

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The option 1 that you mentioned does not make good UX just because your legend feels like a label, at first user will not have any clue that it can be selected.

Option 2 will be fine but I would suggest few enhancement that you can add to that:

-> You can make the text of selected legend Bold.

-> Or you can also make UI better like shown below:

[image]

-> Use the border and background color as per legend (e.g. green for completed, yellow for pending)

-> If you prefer more customiztion than replace circle radio with the checkbox that you mentioned in option 2.

Design I have showed is particularly for mobile, but I hope you got the hint on how to take advantage of it in your website.